# Сайт на asp.net. Отказано в доступе. Сообщение об ошибке 401.2. В чем проблема?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

С Asp.net не сильно много работала. Дали задание на работе решить проблемы с сайтом (примерно 2016го года он). Проблемы из разряда косметических, то бишь работа со страницами и с запросами к базе данных.
При попытке запустить сайт из проекта для отладки в Visual Studio 2019 выдаёт ошибку, которую никак не могу решить. Большинство советов, что нашла в интернете по запросу на эту ошибку, пробовала, но они не помогли. В свойствах проверку подлинности Windows, как советовали, включала, начал просить логин и пароль. Какие нужны данные для входа - не понятно.
Скрин ошибки прилагаю. Далее прилагаю ту же ошибку в тексте, если так удобнее. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Отказано в доступе.
Описание: При доступе к ресурсам, которые требуются для обслуживания данного запроса, возникла ошибка. Возможно, этот сервер не настроен для доступа к требуемому URL-адресу.

Сообщение об ошибке 401.2.: Нет прав доступа: Вход не выполнен из-за настройки сервера.  Убедитесь, что у вас есть право просмотра этого каталога или страницы на основе предоставленных вами учетных данных и методов аутентификации, включенных на веб-сервере.  Обратитесь за помощью к администратору веб-сервера.

Информация о версии: Платформа Microsoft .NET Framework, версия:4.0.30319; ASP.NET, версия:4.7.3062.0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: разверните сайт локально в IIS (Internet Information Services) и установите нужные настройки проверки подлинности. IIS -> сайты -> ваш сайт -> Проверка подлинности

Comment: У вас нет доступа к странице сайта. Почему так происходит без кода/настроек сайта вам никто не скажет. Если включаете windows аутентификацию и начинает просить логин и пароль - то вводить надо логин и пароль от windows.

Comment: Слишком мало информации в вопросе. Во-первых, вполне возможно, что сайт ваш является каким-то рабочим порталом, который работает внутри организации и хитро связан с Active Directory - типа, вам нужно настроить чтобы на локальной машине работало. Во-вторых, вы пишете что работаете с vs2019 - и ваша проблема может быть из разряда "используете слишком новый тулчейн" и в интернете вы первая, кто столкнулся с подобным. PS Уже второй вопрос по vs2019 - пойти себе что и поставить для поиграться?)

Comment: Скорее всего у вас приложение требует win auth, а она отключена по умолчанию в IIS Express. Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053666/